# What is the purpose of the bash `suspend` builtin command?

Tags: bash, signals, suspend, shell-builtin

I typed `help suspend` and got this short explanation:

```
suspend: suspend [-f]
    Suspend shell execution.

    Suspend the execution of this shell until it receives a SIGCONT signal.
    Unless forced, login shells cannot be suspended.

    Options:
      -f    force the suspend, even if the shell is a login shell

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless job control is not enabled or an error occurs.
```

How I understand this is: I type `suspend` and the terminal freezes, not even strg + c can unfreeze it. But when I open another terminal and search for the PID for the frozen one and type `kill -SIGCONT PID-NR` a SIGCONT signal is send to the frozen terminal and thaws it up, so that it gets unfrozen.

But, what is the actual purpose of suspending a terminal? Which every day applications are typical for it? What did the people who made it a shell builtin have in mind?

Comment: avoid running external programs (kill) for suspend.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you start a shell from another shell, you can suspend the inner one. Say when using `su`, and wanting to switch back to the regular user for a moment:

```
user$ su
Password: ...
root# do something
root# suspend
user$ do something as the ordinary user again
user$ fg
root# ...
```

(If you do that, don't forget the privileged shell open in the background...)

Similarly, if you escape to a shell from some other program (the `!` command in e.g. `less`), you can still suspend the shell. But I wouldn't expect many other programs to handle it nicely when they launch a subprocess, which then suspends itself.

Comment: I just tried running `vim`, and did a `:sh` to get a subshell (specifically, a `zsh` subshell).  Running `suspend` popped me into the *original* shell (it suspended both the subshell and vim).

Comment: @Kevin, `zsh` seems smarter in that than `bash`, I tried escaping to both from both `less` and `vi` (Debian's `vim.tiny`): `zsh` stopped the parent app too, `bash` hung the whole thing. `bash` to `bash` works though.

Comment: i was not aware, that what i type sudo su a subshell is started. when I typed suspend in the main shell the shell simply freezes, but how you showed, when i supsend it inside the subshell I go automatically back to the main shell.

Answer (score 27):

That's the equivalent of pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> in other commands.

It suspends the shell and gives control back to parent shell or process if any.

Example:

```
zsh$ bash
bash-4.4$ cd /
bash-4.4$ suspend
zsh: suspended (signal)  bash
zsh$ fg
[1]  + continued  bash
bash-4.4$ pwd
/
```

The feature comes from csh, the shell of BSD (where job control comes from) [in the early 80s](https://github.com/weiss/original-bsd/commit/6621ecae58f277200aa18ceebf9ad63ac84fe34e#diff-82d87abbdedb340595ee734af81c0a3aR134).

In AT&T `ksh`, it's a builtin alias for `kill -s STOP $$` ([yes, without the quotes!](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/10))

In your case, `bash` was probably the one started directly by the terminal emulator. And your terminal emulator didn't expect the process to be suspended.

That `bash` was a session leader. If the session leader is suspended, if we take the view of old time terminals, the user will have no way to resume it.

`bash` addresses that by refusing to `suspend` if it's a login shell. But in your case, your terminal emulator probably doesn't start `bash` in login mode, so that safeguard is not in place.

`zsh` and `mksh` don't have the problem because they send a `SIGTSTP` (the one also sent upon <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>) signal like csh instead of `SIGSTOP` (and to the caller's process group for `mksh` like in csh, and to the main process group of the shell for `zsh`, not the `$$` process alone). `SIGTSTP` is ignored when delivered to an orphaned process group, and the group of the leader qualifies. The idea is that SIGTSTP should not suspend something that is not resumable by a user.

In `mksh` or `yash`, one can also use `suspend` to have a subshell suspend itself:

```
$ (set -x; sleep 1; suspend; sleep 2)
+ sleep 1
+ suspend
[1] + Stopped(SIGSTOP)     (set -x; sleep 1; suspend; sleep 2)
$ fg
[1] (set -x; sleep 1; suspend; sleep 2)
+ sleep 2
```

That wouldn't work with `zsh` that sends the SIGTSTP to the main process group instead of the caller. In any shell that has `kill` builtin, one can always use `kill -s TSTP 0` instead.

Comment: You can cite a common use for suspend is:  in bash (and probably lots of shells) : when you started a long command, and don't want to interrupt it but whished you did that in the background (ie, you want `command .... &` but you forgot the `&` and now wish you could add it without interrupting the command) :  you can : `ctrl-z`, and then type: `bg` to resume the latest suspended task in the background. (or `bg %n` to do this with task number `n`.  Use `jobs` to get a list of suspended or running tasks)

Comment: @OlivierDulac, that wouldn't explain what the actual `suspend` *command* is for.